# Shutdown Takes too much time in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: shutdown, 15.04, performance

I upgraded Ubuntu 14.10 to 15.04 about a month before, after upgrading I'm facing too much of performance issues and it also takes too much time to shutdown. Is there problems with this new release of ubuntu because after upgrading from 14.04 things are getting worse and worse, 14.10 version was little bad in performance but 15.04 has drastically degraded the performance of what one expects from a linux distributions.

Thank you.

Comment: Press F12 during shutdown to see what's going on.

Comment: pressing f12 during shutdown doesn't show anything, for your information I'd like tell you I'm using HP pavailion laptop if it helps to better understand the problem.

Comment: Then open `/etc/default/grub` with elevated privileges and remove `quiet splash` from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, save, exit, run `sudo update-grub` and reboot. At next boot, the boot splash will be gone and you will see the log during boot and shutdown. Now you should be able to see what happens on shutdown and what takes how long.

Comment: @the_Seppi I tried this, but still problem is not gone it still persists, if I shutdown my machine after 1 or 2 hrs of use it shows the processes shutting down but if I shutdown after 15-20 hrs of usage nothing showed up in the screen, its just a black screen with cursor at top left.

Answer (score 1):

First this may be [bug #1464917:](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1464917)

If this affects you please go there and let them know by clicking the link "This affects me" above the intial bug report.

After the shutdown or reboot has hanged with this message.

`Reached target Shutdown`

You may only see this if you have removed the splash screen, if you don't see this message you can still try the following.

Try [Sysrq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key)

1. Hold down the Alt and SysRq (Print Screen) keys.
2. While holding those down, type the following keys in order, several
   seconds apart: REISUB
3. Computer should reboot.

Once it reboots immediately try shutdown button again, it should shutdown properly.  Please add your name to the "This Affects Me" link at the launchpad bug site linked above.

You can also try the following after it hangs.

Try and login tty1 and reboot

1. Press `Ctrl+Alt+F1` or `Ctrl+Alt+F2` or `Ctrl+Alt+F3` ...
2. Write your username (lowercase, the name of the user folder in
   /home) and hit Enter
3. Write your password (nothing will appear) and hit Enter

If your password and username are correct, you are now logged in.

If that fails try `Ctrl+Alt+Del` a couple times at that point in the tty1 screen.

You might see a message that states the machine is going to reboot and then it should do just that after a minute or so.

Its better than a hard boot - until its fixed.

In the bug notes it is reported that you can upgrade to Vivid-Proposed and it fixes the issue but some still see this after that upgrade.  It might be worth a shot.